# CSS card in parallel with icons

Tags: html, css

I know this might be a simple thing. I am struggling to add small cards in parallel with icons inside the card and some text like the one shared in the screenshot below.I can't use bootstrap for this, I am using material lite(https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#buttons-section) Sharing the screenshot below on what I am trying to achieve. [image]

Comment: So where is your code?

Comment: What is the question or the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create something like this I'd suggest that you use CSS Flexbox. With the help of that, you can divide the card into portions. e.g. you can have two main blocks and so on as shown in the picture. And for the blocks which have items in a row, you just use flex-direction: row; and where it's on the top of each other, like columns, you use flex-direction: column. Research a little on flexbox and creating something like this won't be an issue!

[image]

Comment: This is not the only way to go about making portions in this card, you can make these portions however you feel comfortable, I just did this one as an example.